# Updated version of the application is not visible on play store

Tags: android, google-play-console

I published the updated version of the application on play console and got the conformation email that app is published on play store . But play store does not show the current updated version. for more details have a look towards attached image and guide me if I missed something.

Play console shows me that

https://i.stack.imgur.com/vQOYE.png

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, your screenshot shows that you set the release rollout to only 20% of your installed base, so only 1 in 5 people are going to see it.

[Here](https://support.google.com/googleplay/android-developer/answer/6346149#increase&zippy=%2Cincrease-your-staged-rollout-percentage) are instructions for managing staged rollouts

Comment: so now what I have to do to make it available for all

Comment: Edit the release, and change the rollout to 100%